# Geolocation in JavaScript not returning the position

Tags: javascript

I am running the following code on my localhost and also on https://early-position.surge.sh/ but it does get the position even though I allow it.

```
if(!navigator.geolocation) {
    console.log('Geolocation is not supported by your browser')
} else {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        console.log(position)
    }, function() {

    })
}
```

Anyone familiar with this issue?

Comment: its working for me at https://early-position.surge.sh/

Comment: @Craicerjack Thanks! I am not sure if there is something different about my browser. I am using Chrome Version 88.0.4324.182 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: do you see an error at all?

Comment: No error nothing displayed on the console.

Comment: Running on macOS? Try enabling GPS access through your browser.

Comment: Running on macOS, Catalina

Comment: Just check your settings first @azamsharp Might be disabled through macOS itself.

Comment: Got it to work! I relaunched the browser and gave location access again. Thanks!

Comment: Log your second callback parameters. It reveals the error